# Why is the jQuery smooth scroll jumping on the page?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery smooth scroll on the following page:

http://test4.coretechs.com/coretechs_site/promo-test

When you click one of the navigation items, it will scroll animate to the `<div id=''>` for that navigation item. The animated scroll works, but most of the time there is a jump on the page before the scrolling happens.

I'm experiencing this problem in Firefox and Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea why this jumping is occurring?

Comment: it is working fine for me on firefox. which version of firefox you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$("ul.menu a.promonav_services, ul.menu a.promonav_portfolio, ul.menu a.promonav_contact").click(function (e) {
    e.preventdefault(); //stop the default behavior of anchor tag
    var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    scrollToAnchor(href);
});
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. What's wrong with me?!!!! Thank you for pointing that out. That completely slipped my mind. Now works like a charm. Thanks Tushar Gupta.